# Java Hibernate Bug Wrong Parameter Binding

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-5.x

I have this simple Hibernate code.

```
public List<Student>bug(){
    //SimpleCriteria
    final Criterion eq = and(Restrictions.eq("fdl","N"),Restrictions.eq("cid",1),Restrictions.eq("did",2));
    return currentSession().createCriteria(Student.class)                
           .createAlias("school","s",JoinType.INNER_JOIN,Restrictions.eq("zipCode",1764))               
           .createAlias("address","a",JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN,eq)
           .setProjection(addProjection("id"))
           .setResultTransformer(transformer(Student.class))                
           .list();
}
```

The problem is the parameters and somehow disorder or mixed or in a wrong position each one the problem arises when i create two createAlias both with at least a criterion like this(See Update below)

createAlias With Some Criterions

```
createAlias("school","s",JoinType.INNER_JOIN,Restrictions.eq("zipCode",1764))               
createAlias("address","a",JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN,eq)
```

The sql generated seems good..

```
select
    this_.ID as y0_ 
from
    student this_ 
left outer join
    address address2_ 
        on this_.C05=address2_.ID 
        and (
            (
                address2_.FDL=? 
                and address2_.CID=? 
                and address2_.DID=?
            ) 
        ) 
inner join
    school school_ 
        on this_.C03=school_.ID 
        and (
            school_.C06=? //ZIPCODE
        )
```

Even when i see the log4j i can see the wrong binding 
[image]

You can see the zip code value 1764 is bind to the first parameter which is address2_.FDL

```
binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [1764]
```

Later the second parameter which is cid is assigned the correct previous value for fdl which is 'N'

```
Message: binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [N]
```

Later the third parameter which is did is assigned the correct previous value for cid which is 1

```
binding parameter [3] as [INTEGER] - [1]
```

Later the four parameter which is zipCode is assigned the correct previous value for did which is 2

```
binding parameter [4] as [INTEGER] - [2]
```

Of course the generatedsql match log4j binding

```
select
    this_.ID as y0_ 
from
    student this_ 
left outer join
    address address2_ 
        on this_.C05=address2_.ID 
        and (
            (
                address2_.FDL=1764 
                and address2_.CID='N'
                and address2_.DID=1
            ) 
        ) 
inner join
    school school_ 
        on this_.C03=school_.ID 
        and (
            school_.C06=2 //ZIPCODE
        )
```

As you can see the binding is clearly wrong.

Expected<---------------->Reality

```
1 parameter fdl should be bind to 'N' but is bind to zipCode value which is 1764
2 parameter cid should be bind to 1 but is bind to fdl value which is 'N'
3 parameter did should be bind to 2 but is bind to cid value which is 1
4 parameter zipCode should be bind to 1764 but is bind to did value which is 2
```

What i think is happening Hibernate mix the parameters positions for some reason.

I was using Hibernate 4.3.4 when this problem come across but i see a similiar bug which was fixed in 5.2.2 https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10991 and i upgrade to Hibernate 5.2.2 and the same problem come across i have seen a lot of forum reporting this problem why hibernate doesn't fix it? Of course i have workarounds but this problem is very annoying

If i use the 2 createAlias with not criterion everything works like expected

```
createAlias("school","s",JoinType.INNER_JOIN,Restrictions.eq("zipCode",1764))               
createAlias("address","a",JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN)
```

Environment

```
Java: 1.8.0_74; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.74-b02
Hibernate 5.2.2 and 4.3.4 tested in both.
Netbeans NetBeans IDE 8.1 (Build 201510222201)
```

Another similiar forums

```
https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=947018
https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=971534
https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-2496
https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-1743
```

**UPDATE**

The parameters goes wrong even when are 2 parameters

```
public List<Student>bug(){
    return currentSession().createCriteria(Student.class)                
     .createAlias("school","s",JoinType.INNER_JOIN,Restrictions.eq("zipCode",1764))               
     .createAlias("address","a",JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN,Restrictions.eq("fdl","N"))
     .setProjection(addProjection("id"))
     .setResultTransformer(transformer(Student.class))                
     .list();
}
```

As you can see the binding is clearly wrong.

Expected<---------------->Reality

```
1 parameter fdl should be bind to 'N' but is bind to zipCode value which is 1764
2 parameter zipCode should be bind to 1764 but is bind to fdl value which is 'N'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*... and the same problem come across i have seen a lot of forum reporting this problem why hibernate doesn't fix it?*

[`org.hibernate.Criteria`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#criteria) API is considered deprecated:

> Hibernate offers an older, legacy `org.hibernate.Criteria` API which
>   should be considered deprecated. No feature development will target
>   those APIs. Eventually, Hibernate-specific criteria features will be
>   ported as extensions to the JPA
>   `javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery`.

Thus you should not expect a lot of effort related to `org.hibernate.Criteria` API (including bug fixing) in future versions.

I suggest you migrate to JPA `CriteriaQuery` API. However, I personally don't like it either, and I always use either JPQL/HQL directly or QueryDSL which I find as a very good balance between JPQL string-ness and the high verbosity of `CriteriaQuery` APIs.